# How to check value is null or not in flutter? im developing a flutter application with webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm developing application in flutter using WebView and i want to check the cookie value consistently the value is null or not with the help of CookieManager . The current condition is i am checking this in init with timer.periodic consistently but this may decrease my application performance when it will go live. I am looking for a alternate solution for this. Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RumenRusanov i'm checking the value of cookie in init consistently with timer.periodic and i want to check  the value when  it is null so i want to navigate to the home screen.